# Spring rest with Spring Boot: Upload MultipartFile and Json object as parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I know this question was asked on stackoverflow before. However, I haven't found an answer that actually tests the service using, for example, Postman.

I have followed the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers) and my service is pretty much the same as described on the documentation:

```
@PostMapping("/someUrl")
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadFile(@RequestPart(name="foo", required = false) Foo foo, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
}
```

When I try to heat my service using Postman, I got the following error:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request

And on postman, I got the following return

[image: Postman]

**The question is**: Is it possible to call my service using Postman? If it is, what parameters am I missing?

Comment: Are you posting to the correct url ('/someUrl' in your code example)?

Comment: Yes. I'm posting to the correct URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible to call your service using Postman.

Instead of sending JSON as text, create a file (e.g. *test.json*) containing JSON data that you want to send:

```
{
    "teste": "abc"
}
```

Then in form-data section change the type of your `foo` field from *Text* to *File* and choose JSON file that you've created.

And that's it. Click *Send* and your request should be processed without any error.

**Note:** Header should be left empty i.e. it should not contain any custom Content-Type value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is some issue with Postman while using multipart file with json data. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576

You can use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) to test your service like below.

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "foo={\"teste\":\"abc\"};type=application/json" -F "file=@amazon.png"  http://localhost:8080/v1/files/someURL
```